# Чем отличаются союзы "но" и "однако", в том числе в правиле Розенталя о присоединительных союзах?

Tags: союзы

1. Обычно союзы ***НО*** и ***ОДНАКО*** считаются **синонимами**,  но ведь чем-то они **отличаются.**

Часто можно встретить мнение, что они используются в разных **стилях,** а есть ли между ними **грамматическое и семантическое** отличие?

Вероятно, смысловую разницу между ними можно определить и **по этимологии** этих слов (один — однако). Так почему же ***один***?

2. В теме «Присоединительные союзы в СПП» союз ***НО*** может отделяться или не отделяться   запятой от подчинительного союза, а союз  ***ОДНАКО*** обычно отделяется.

Comment: А какая этимология у но?

Comment: Так это  вы, сэр, мне расскажите, а я вам печеньку дам))  Или много печенек...